# header fade in on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello I'm trying to make that each header have to fadeIn when window.scrollTop is greater than header position but my code doesn't work and I get strange html instead of my headers. Any idea?

```
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.inner h2').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            var header = $(this);           
            var title = header.html();
            header.html('');        
            var arrayTitle = title.split('');
            var i = 0;              

            var interval = setInterval(function(){
            if (i > arrayTitle.length) 
            {
              header.html(title);        // wipe out the <span> tags
              clearInterval(interval);
            } 
            else
            {
              $('<span>')
                .html(arrayTitle[i])
                .appendTo(header)
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(50);                    
                i++;      
            }
            }, 50);

        }            
    }); 

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/2005/

Comment: If you are not posting your code, don't link to your fiddle. The rule is there for a reason.

Comment: It appears to me that several appendTo-s (of fadeIn-s?) are happaning at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

### [Solved Check Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/2009/)  **And** [Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/2010/)

What I did Changed the use of span instead used a `var temp`to append header text character by char and each time this temp is passed as the content into header tags innerhtml as `header.html(temp)`

***Changed the code little bit but does the trick***

```
            var temp='';
            var interval = setInterval(function(){
            if (i > arrayTitle.length) 
            {
              header.html(title);        // wipe out the <span> tags
              clearInterval(interval);
            } 
            else
            { 

             if (i < arrayTitle.length) 
            {

                temp =temp+arrayTitle[i];
            } 


              //  alert(temp);
                header.html(temp).fadeIn(1000);

                 i++; 
            }
            }, 50);
```

Comment: It still doesn't work headers text is hidding when I scroll down.

Comment: @user3699634 have u checked the demo1 its not hiding

Comment: Yes I have when I scroll I see only first letter I want to show all of the text and animation once when user scroll down first time no everytime.

Comment: @user3699634 be specfic do you want it happen only one time?? the first time you scroll or do you wan it to happen each up/down scroll and another thing how do you want your header to appear it works fine if you scroll slowly check by scrolling one or two paces down in slow manner

Comment: I want to happen it only one time when I scroll down and it show it should disappear when I scroll up.

Comment: @user3699634 wait dont go i will show you something and tell me is that you want

Comment: Not really because headers disapears when I scroll down they should appear when I scroll down letter by letter.